# Persist Solr data on Azure app service inside docker container

Tags: azure, docker, solr, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted Solr as a docker Container using standard Solr image for docker on Azure web app container.

I have also set WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to true. And for several weeks everything was good. But just found that the solr core was missing suddenly and after checking further I found that all our previous data including solr core configurations are gone and it's just the default Solr that was running. It seems that all configs and data are not persisting. I checked with restart when we deployed and it seems that data was persisting at that time. But we lost it suddenly. There was no log into Solr as well.. it was just like a new Solr docker deployment.

I think that there is an issue with persisting solr data using the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE setting as it's not reliable.

I am looking for quickest possible way to have persisting data for solr. What can be done here?

Comment: WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE  does nothing for me too.
following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#use-persistent-shared-storage

So I'm trying to persist in a FileShare within a storage account but linking the webapp to this is proving challenging (e.g., Permissions errors even if I have full ownership of both) 
following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux#link-storage-to-your-app

Comment: Once you enable the same, you will need to use it in volumes like this...

volumes:
        - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/solr-sitecore-configsets:/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets
        - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/solr-sitecore-data:/var/solr/data

Comment: This article has resolved our issue: https://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-solr-docker-app-service-on-azure

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I should've made it clearer, I'm not using solr. I am trying to persist a folder in the webapp and linking it to azure storageaccount. so the data would be sitting on a fileshare and the dockerised webapp should be able to write to the storage, then be destroyed, but the storage keep the changes made by the webapp.

Comment: Update: found a guide that solved my problem:
https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2019/07/25/mounting-volumes-on-azure-web-app-for-containers/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, I believe the problem is happening because you're not persisting the state outside app services. It worths to mention you don't "own" the VM's where your apps and containers are running, so you need to persist the state outside those vms. You need to add volumes to your containers which will be persisted on storage accounts.

```
az webapp config storage-account add 
        --resource-group "my-resource-group" `
            --name "my-appservices" `
            --custom-id "volume-mount"  `
            --storage-type AzureBlob `
            --account-name "mystorageaccount"  `
            --share-name "container-volume" `
            --access-key "<redacted>" `
            --mount-path "/config/" `
            --slot-setting `
            --output table
```

Comment: I already have a volume defined in docker-compose and which is used by the docker. However, still it doesn't work correctly. Please advise

Comment: I added a storage to docker, not sure if this resolved the issue

Comment: you'll need to check the files and compare before / after the restart the differences